# Submission of an article from the XXX Medical 'Center' to a journal that requires British spelling

Tags: spelling

I am editing a scientific paper that specifies British spelling. But the name of the author's research institute is The XXX Center for Medical Research. 
Should I change this to Centre?

Comment: This might be a better question to ask on [academia.se]. But I’d advise to leave the name of the center as the actual name of the center.

Answer (score 1):

No. Proper nouns should retain their spelling, even when this is at odds with the normal style and spelling rules. So, The Atlanta Center for Medical Research is a centre of research into medical matters.